# ServiceNow - Data Transform Script Debug

Tags: servicenow

I am using a data transform to import a large .csv of emails into a Watchlist field. My .csv is in the following format:

`"ipsum@test.com", "ipsum@test.com, lorem@test.com",,"ipsum@tests.com"`

I am using the following script to link the imported emails to User records, however my data transform ignores all records despite me manually confirming the emails exist, is there something wrong in this script?

```
answer = (function transformEntry(source) {

    var grUsers = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
    var users = String(source.u__users).split(",");
    var query = 'email=LIKE' + String(users[0]);
    var i = 1;
    while(i != users.length){
        query = query + '^ORemailLIKE' + String(users[i]);
        i++;
    }

    grUsers.addEncodedQuery(query);
    grUsers.query();
    return grUsers.join(',');

})(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. Using **split(",")** is not enough if the format you are showing is correct. You need to strip the quotes as well
2. Using **email=LIKE** should be **emailLIKE**, no **=** sign

Here is an example based on your data:

```
var data = '"alpha@test.com","beta@test.com","lorem@test.com","ipsum@tests.com"';
var users = String(data).split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
 gs.print(users[i])
}

var query = 'email=LIKE' + String(users[0]);
gs.print(query);
```

Running this in Background Scripts I get:

```
*** Script: "alpha@test.com"
*** Script: "beta@test.com"
*** Script: "lorem@test.com"
*** Script: "ipsum@tests.com"
*** Script: email=LIKE"alpha@test.com"
```

Here's the fixed one:

```
var data = '"alpha@test.com","beta@test.com","lorem@test.com","ipsum@tests.com"';
var users = String(data).split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
 users[i] = users[i].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
}

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
 gs.print(users[i])
}

var query = 'emailLIKE' + String(users[0]);
gs.print(query);
```

Result:

```
*** Script: alpha@test.com
*** Script: beta@test.com
*** Script: lorem@test.com
*** Script: ipsum@tests.com
*** Script: emailLIKEalpha@test.com
```